# JList does not clear

Tags: swing, jlist

I have an issue with removing old elements from my lists. I tried using the methods `clear()` and `removeAllElements()` and `removeAll()` wherever I could but that does not seem to clear them.

To help you understand the situation a little bit better:

`d1` is an `ArrayList` that contains all available devices in our program.

`availList2` and `availList3` are using the `DefaultListModel`.

We wanted to make it so that when the user loads the products from the proper text file, if he did that a second time the products already listed in our gui would be overwritten with the ones in the original text file. However we ended up having duplicates of the products, even though we used the `clear()` method in both the `d1` (`ArrayList`) and the `JList`.

Any useful tips or possible causes would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

```
if(ev.getSource() == load_availables) {
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(mainApp.this);

    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        d1.returnDevices().removeAll(d1.returnDevices());
        availList2.clear();
        availList3.clear();
        //availList2.removeAllElements();
        //availList3.removeAllElements();
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        read.ReadDevices(file);
        for(int i = 0; i < read.Size(); i++) {
            d1.add_AvailableDevices(read.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list is not cleared then I would suggest you don't have the proper reference to the `DefaultListModel` that is being used by the `JList` when you invoke the `clear()` method.

Start by the reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Download the `ListDemo` code and play with it. Change the "Fire" button to use the `clear()` method on the `DefaultListModel` to prove to yourself that is all you need to do.

Once you see the code working then you figure out how your code is different from the `ListDemo` working version.